# Check one Checkbox to Check All, Customized Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want the checking the "even numbers" box to uncheck all the even numbers listed in my fiddle. It currently works functionally, but I want the individual box for each even number to uncheck when the corresponding number is not displayed (it will make more sense once you see the fiddle).

If you uncheck "even numbers" I want the "two" "four" and "six" boxes to turn gray, and to turn pink again once you check "even numbers."

Currently, the checkboxes work functionally, but do not all display properly.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "evennumbers") {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".two.number").show();
        $(".four.number").show();
        $(".six.number").show();
      } else {
        $(".two.number").hide();
        $(".four.number").hide();
        $(".six.number").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.hide_this').fadeOut(1)
})

$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "two") {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".two.number").show();
      } else {
        $(".two.number").hide();
      }
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "four") {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".four.number").show();
      } else {
        $(".four.number").hide();
      }
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "six") {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".six.number").show();
      } else {
        $(".six.number").hide();
      }
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "one") {
      if (this.checked) {
        $(".one.number").show();
      } else {
        $(".one.number").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#demo {
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#demo .parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #282D31;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
  text-align: center;
}
#demo .parent:hover,
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
#demo .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0;
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
#demo .wrapper:active .content {
  height: 153px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
#demo .content:hover {
  height: 153px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
#demo .content ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#demo .content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.styledCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.styledCheckbox {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.styledCheckbox label {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.styledCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="demo">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <section>
              <div class="styledCheckbox" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="evennumbers" name="colorCheckbox" value="evennumbers" checked>
                <label for="evennumbers">
                  <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; font-weight: bold">
                    Even_Numbers
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </li>
          <li>
            <section>
              <div class="styledCheckbox" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="one" value="one" checked>
                <label for="one">
                  <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; font-weight: bold">
                    One
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </li>
          <li>
            <section>
              <div class="styledCheckbox" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="colorCheckbox" value="two" checked>
                <label for="two">
                  <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; font-weight: bold">
                    Two
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </li>
          <li>
            <section>
              <div class="styledCheckbox" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="four" name="colorCheckbox" value="four" checked>
                <label for="four">
                  <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; font-weight: bold">
                    Four
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </li>
          <li>
            <section>
              <div class="styledCheckbox" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="six" name="colorCheckbox" value="six" checked>
                <label for="six">
                  <p style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; font-weight: bold">
                    Six
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">Display These #s</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="number one" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
  <p>one</p>
</div>
<div class="number two" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
  <p>two</p>
</div>
<div class="number four" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
  <p>four</p>
</div>
<div class="number six" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
  <p>six</p>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/k37jqj2c/4/)

Comment: Sorry, i can't see your fiddle yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your evennumbers checkbox click handler to look like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("value") == "evennumbers") {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(".even").show();
      $(".even-checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".even").hide();
      $(".even-checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
});
```

Add class even-checkbox to the checkboxes for two, four, and six:

```
<input class="even-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="two" name="colorCheckbox" value="two" checked>
```

Add class even to the divs of number two, number four, and number six:

```
<div class="number one" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
<p>one</p>
```

```
<div class="number two even" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
<p>two</p>
```

```
<div class="number four even" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
<p>four</p>
```

```
<div class="number six even" style="text-align: center; font-size: xx-large">
<p>six</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I explained the issue properly. When I uncheck "even numbers" the numbers 2, 4, and 6 do not display, but their corresponding checkmarks remain "checked" (bright pink).

Comment: This line takes care of that problem. `$(".even-checkbox").prop('checked', false);`